# Cycles Emission Material Receiving Shadows

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, lighting, shadows, emission

I am trying to follow [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Q8PwcDzb8Y) tutorial. Around 36:00 in the tutorial, he adds an UV sphere with an emission material that will eventually become the sun. However, when I follow the exact same steps, my object does not seem to emit anything, and instead receives shadows from the lamp. It is the very small object in the background of the picture below.

[image]

I have tried everything including:

- Turning up the strength of the emission node up to 10, 20, and 50
- Material Properties > Settings > Shadow Mode > None
- Object Properties > Visibility > Ray Visibility > Deselecting Shadow
- Adding a Light Path node, connecting it to the value of a Map Range node, and connecting the result to the strength of the emission node
- Changing the sun lamp to an area lamp
- Disabling the sun lamp altogether
- Disabling my HDRI background altogether (note I have the ray visibility for the HDRI set to camera only and also have transparency selected for compositing purposes)

Nothing seems to be working.

Blender Version: 2.92

Material Settings:

[image]
[image]

Render Settings:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome, please add some screenshots of your material nodes and render settings, the more info, the better

Comment: Did you perhaps add a second material *slot* instead of putting the second material into the existing slot?

Comment: Make sure you really are using cycles, your screenshots are showing cycles material on the first one and EEVEE material on the second image

Comment: @Emir I am confused as to what you mean by this. The first two screenshots are of the exact same material. The third and fourth screenshots are of the cycles render settings.

Comment: @AllenSimpson This was helpful, thank you. I had to switch to edit mode and assign the mesh to the object.